# In javascript, what are the differences between export and export default

Tags: javascript, export

I know there can be only one "export default" in one file. Beside that, what are the differences? both of them can be imported by other files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They change the way the exported bits are imported.

Importing a named export:

```
import {namedThing} from './otherFile.js';
```

Importing a default export:

```
import thing from './otherFile';
```

With a default export, you can rename the thing you are importing on the way in, like

```
import hoobajoob from './otherFile';
```

There are many other ways to do imports:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Answer (score 0):

default export doesn't have to have a name in the exporting file

For example:
`export default function doStuff() {...}` or `export default function() {...}`

Named export always has to have a value with a name. For example:
`export function doStuff() {...}`